# Stripe how to create a token for a Credit Card stored with customer using iOS / Parse

Tags: ios, objective-c, stripe-payments

Im in the process of creating automatic charges to Stripe out of an iOS app.

I can:

- collect card info
- create a token with publishable key
- create a new customer and attach that collected credit card to the new customer by using the token

Adding the card to the customer however, uses up the token (token seems to be single use only according to Stripe), so I need a new one for a later charge.

Now, Id like to create a charge, which leads to the question:

- How can I create a new token from the same stored credit card? (Without having all the infos like card number etc. again)

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The create charge api allows you to pass the customer id to charge the customer's stored card and token is not required.