# Keeping credit card information safe with Parse or Stripe

Tags: ios, parse-platform, stripe-payments, credit-card

I am working on a app that I need to store credit card information. Would it be safe to use the Parse ACL like this?

```
PFObject *privateNote = [PFObject objectWithClassName:@"_User"];
privateNote[@"creditCard"] = @1234;
privateNote.ACL = [PFACL ACLWithUser:[PFUser currentUser]];
[privateNote saveInBackground];
```

[Or should I use stripe to keep the information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32784797/stripe-how-to-create-a-token-for-a-credit-card-stored-with-customer-using-ios).

Comment: You should use Stripe, storing credit card info yourself would require a much more extensive PCI complaint setup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Handling raw card information (i.e. card numbers) yourself would require you to be PCI certified, which is a long and costly process and not a viable option for most entities.

Stripe and other modern payment processors make it easy to be [PCI compliant](https://stripe.com/docs/security#pci-dss-guidelines) by providing means to send the payment information directly from the customer to the payment processor, without the merchant (i.e. you) having direct access to the PCI-sensitive information. You should definitely let Stripe (or another payment processor) handle the card information for you.

(Disclaimer: I work for Stripe.)